# How to extend the regular expression that works for one pair to many pairs

Tags: c++, regex, recursion

I have written a code to find all matches to the pattern like `23<=34` or `123<>2000` in the given file. More generally, `a(sign)b` where `sign` ∈ **{** `=<`, `=`, `>`, `<=`, `<>`, `>=` **}** and `a`,`b` ∈ N.

Now, I got stuck on extending this code to identify many joint patterns like `a(sign)b(sign)c(sign)...(sign)d`. This reminds me of finding the `gcd` of many numbers using only the `gcd` for two numbers. But I don't really know how to proceed. **Assume** that we **already** have the function `solved()` that works for only one pair (the code below if needed).

**Summary of the problem:**
Creating a function that more or less looks like this:

```
void solve(string text) {
   // using solved(string text) [but optional]
}
```

Maybe there are other ways, and I would be more than happy to see them!

---

Below is the code I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;
#define REGEX_SIGN   "(=<|=|>|<=|<>|>=)"
#define REGEX_DIGIT  "[0-9]"
#define REGEX_NUMBER "[^0]\\d*"

void check(string text) {

  regex sign(REGEX_SIGN);
  regex digit(REGEX_DIGIT);
  regex number(REGEX_NUMBER); 
  regex relation(REGEX_NUMBER REGEX_SIGN REGEX_NUMBER);

  string word = "";

  for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {

    if (text[i] == ' ') {

      regex_match(word, relation) ? cout << "✔️  " : cout << "☒  ";
      cout << word << " ";
      
      cout << endl;
      word = "";

    } else {
      word += text[i];
    }
  }

}

int main() {

  string line, text;

  ifstream fin;
  fin.open("name.txt");

  if (fin.good()) {

    while (getline(fin, line)) {
      text += line + " ";
    }

    check(text);    
  }
  return 0;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are looking for

`REGEX_NUMBER "(" REGEX_SIGN REGEX_NUMBER ")+"`

[Regex demo with `\d+((<|=|>|<=|<>|>=)\d+)+`](https://regex101.com/r/5dH8Vx/1/)

[C++ Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e30804715f8827db).

Comment: Actually, those brackets were just to isolate `sign`'s for the explanation of the problem

Comment: @VIVID: notice that I surroung by `( .. )+`, parents are for grouping, `+` is for repetition (1 or more).

Comment: Thanks for the demos! How to avoid the numbers that start with 0? I added the picture at the end of the question with your regex. I tried myself first, but that starts accepting from `=`. It's kind of "not smooth".

Comment: `REGEX_NUMBER` should be `"(0|[1-9]\d*)"` (as zero should be valid IMO).

Comment: I think I got you. Thank you!

Comment: The site does a search instead of exact match, you might use `^` and `$` for start and end. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/J2XpOk/1)